# Error with Angular 1.5 + ngRoute + Mootools 1.6

Tags: angularjs, mootools, compatibility, ngroute, angularjs-1.6

Hello guys I hope you can help me, I have a project that requires me to use angularJs with `ngRoute` and Mootools, my routes are working properly.

it all works fine, but When I add mootools to my HTML it all crashes from the start saying that `$$SanitizeUriProvide` is null, please can someone tell me what is happening in this case?

Comment: Create demo in [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) that replicates problem

Comment: @charlietfl I already solved the issue, apparently it had something to do with the versions of Agular and Mootools, I did the Plunker demo and it ran correctly, all of the functions of both + behavior UI seem to be working properly, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding Angular 1.5, ngRoute 1.45, mootools core 1.5 and mootools more 1.4.

[`PLUNKER LINK HERE`](http://plnkr.co/edit/HSJDFeme45spDZyfcHfq)